# Swing application slow after restart with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, swing, processbuilder

I have a Java Swing application which needs automatic restart. I have implemented it this way:

```
final String javaBin = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
        final File currentJar = new File(UltraCoinApp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());

        /* is it a jar file? */
        if(currentJar.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
        /* Build command: java -jar application.jar */
            final ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
            command.add(javaBin);
            command.add("-jar");
            command.add(currentJar.getPath());

            final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

            builder.start();
        }
        System.exit(0);
```

After the restart the GUI is very slow, all elements respond slow. I suspect this might be because of logging output.

Comment: I'd verify that the first instance has indeed died

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important rule for `ProcessBuilder` is that you absolutely have to read the output of the child process or it will eventually hang.

That means you either have to [redirect stdout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html) while starting the process or you have to read the output in a loop in the parent process.

Another solution is to have an outside process (a script or executable) which runs your JAR in a loop. To terminate, call `System.exit(1)` and examine the exit code in the restart process.

If all that doesn't help, then you'll have to use a profiler to find out where the application is actually spending all the time.

Comment: Redirecting to `ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT` worked.